# Plotting 2D wavelength contour of 2D plane obtained using hilbert haung transform

Tags: python, spectrum

I have a 2D plane of X and Y as the coordinates and Velocity values at each grid point. I have calculated the wavelength of velocity fluctuations in each direction; at every x location and at every z location using hht ( hilbert-haung transform). Now I want to visualize the results in a contour plot that shows X and Y as the coordinates and the combined values of wavelengths as a contour at each grid point.
What is the best way to do that?

Note: I am aware of the 2D fft function that can perform that for periodic signals but the velocity signals are non stationary and thus hht is used.
Thanks.